# Issues with application signature

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create my own version of Gesture Builder. In eclipse I selected android project from existing code and I renamed the project and package name to new gesture. Then I added in android:fadeOffset = "1000" in create gesture xml(so that I can create gestures for letters like t and f) and in AndroidManifest.xml I set the version name to NewGestures and I set a different icon but when I try to run it I get this error message:

"Re-installation failed due to different application signatures. You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data! Do you want to uninstall?"

From what I've seen online I need to match the signature used originally on Gesture Builder, but I've no idea how to do this on eclipse, shouldn't the signature have been handled properly when I created from existing code? Any help would be very much appreciated. I just need this app working so I can get a gestures library for a different application I'm working on for college.

Comment: Is your package name in the manifest changed to your new name as well?

Comment: The package is still package = package="com.android.gesture.builder" and I added in android:versionName="NewGestures". Do I need to change the package itself on all the files?

Comment: How did you try to run this new version? By Exporting the signed APK or just tried running as a debug build?

Comment: reinstall it, it should work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message concerns the application signature. This happens when you are trying to install an application on your device while an application of the same package name is already installed, but signed with a different certificate (see details [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)).

For example:

- You have exported and installed your application using your Google Play keystore (so using your actual developer's certificate), and now you are running/debugging it from Eclipse, implicitely using the debug certificate (which is different)
- You have runned/debugged your application from Eclipse at home on this device, and now your are running it/debugging it from Eclipse with another computer (which is using a different implicit debug certificate)
- etc

Normally, below the error message, you have a button that allows uninstalling/reinstalling. If not, just uninstall your app manually and everything will be fine again.

Answer (score 0):

versionName:

> The version number shown to users. This attribute can be set as a raw
>   string or as a reference to a string resource. The string has no other
>   purpose than to be displayed to users.

package:

> The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.

The package name declared in your manifest.xml is what makes your application unique. Therefore, there can not be two application installed with the same package name at the same time. If you try this, your error occurs.

Comment: Thanks! So should I change my package name in the manifest only or apply it across the activities? I changed it on the activites and now they aren't recognising commands.

Comment: Well, should the certificate be the same, installing a different app but sharing the same package name would be seen as an update by Android: the new app would replace the formerly installed one. And should the certificate be different, the error message 'Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.' would appear.